# Prove the following Theorem. For all positive integers n, some element of the set {n, n + 1} is divisible by 2.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

So far I got:

Either n=2q or n=2q+1 where q is an element of Z.
If n=2q where q is an element of Z then n is divisible by 2.

I'm having trouble figuring out if that is correct and testing if n+1 works as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well if $n$ is of the form $2q+1$, then $n+1 = 2q+2 = 2(q+1)$ is also even, so either way one of them works.

In general, with these kinds of problems, just follow your nose. You computed one case, then I just computed the other, and it turns out that everything worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Two consecutive numbers are one even and one odd. In particular,

$$
2\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor
$$
is the even integer in $\{n,n+1\}$.

Comment: That's what's been required to show.

Comment: Come on, such a question shouldn't have been posted